# Wrong return value

Tags: sql, return

I have to show the products that all of their producers come from the same area (same zip_code). But it returns nothing although it should. What else do I have to correlate in order to return results?

```
create view Data as 
select product_code , Offer.producer_code, zip_code 
from Producer, Offer 
where Producer.producer_code=Offer.producer_code

select product_code 
from  Data
where producer_code =all (select a.zip_code 
                from Data as a, Data as b
                where a.zip_code = b.zip_code)
```

Comment: PLease show table schema, and sample data, and expected results output.  What database platform is this for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the following:

```
SELECT 
    p.product_code,
    o.producer_code
FROM Producer AS p
INNER JOIN Offer AS o
ON p.producer_code = o.producer_code
WHERE p.zip_code=@zip_code
```

The `@zip_code` is the zip_code of the producer you look for. Also, I don't think that the query you have written does what you want. Since you will take all the products that have at least one other product, which has been produced by a producer with the same zip_code. You will not take the products that they have been produced in one certain zip_code.

Comment: @MariaP parakalw. What was the problem?